# How do I get "Goodbye Window" to show up in Java?

Tags: java, window, jpeg

I have a Java network application and this is what I want to do:
After user logs out, his interface window closes. 
Now, I want for another window to show up that will say something like: "Thank you for using our application".
This final window should be borderless and without any available option, more like a plain picture (jpeg? why not?). By clicking on it, user will be sure to close this final window.

I googled and couldn't fin anything on this matter, it's hard to phrase the question.

I hope someone helps me...

Comment: I would add a Timer to close the window after a given time if the user *forgets* to click on it...

Comment: FWIW, speaking as a user, when I close a window, I expect it to go away... not pop up another window to tell me it's gone away and be forced to click again to make the second window go away.

Comment: @Software Monkey: I presume it was a marketing decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JWindow.html

A JWindow is a borderless, undecorated JFrame (no titlebar or buttons).

This should be what you need.

Answer (score 2):

This should help:

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html

You're interested in the `windowClosing` and `windowClosed` events

Answer (score 0):

You have various possibilities, depending on when you want this dialog to display :

- if you want it to display juste before the app closes, use [`addShutdownHook`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread))
- if you want it to display when the last window closes, use [`addWindowListener`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#addWindowListener(java.awt.event.WindowListener))

You can then use a [`JWindow`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JWindow.html) with your image inside, and use [`addMouseListener`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addMouseListener(java.awt.event.MouseListener)) to wait for the user to click on it.

Comment: thanks :)
I've been working all day and my mind forgot about addMouseListener